# How to implement Seams in material design in android?

Tags: android, material-design

I have just started exploring material theme in android. I came across the article of Seams(referd to link at developer.com) [link](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/principles.html#principles-how-paper-works.)
where we can join two materials by a single edge and they move together, I am not able to find how one can achieve this through code. Any help will be much appreciated﻿